# @ResponseStatus клиент не получет сообщение ошибки

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rest

Есть такой код исключения

```
@ResponseStatus(value = BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Login is busy")
public class LoginIsBusyException extends RuntimeException{
}
```

И метод в REST контроллере который может генерировать его

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public void registration(@RequestBody UserRest user) throws LoginIsBusyException{
    userService.checkAlreadyExist(user.getLogin(), user.getMail());
    user.setActive(false);
    UserRest userRest = userService.addUser(user);
    Integer randomToken = randomTokenService.getRandomToken(userRest.getMail());
    mailService.sendMail(randomToken, userRest.getLogin(), userRest.getMail());
}
```

Проблема заключатся в том, что клиент получает только код ошибки но не получает сообщение "Login is busy", Уже пробовал добавлять метод отлавливающий это исключение

```
@ExceptionHandler(LoginIsBusyException.class)
public void handleException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Login is busy");
}
```

Однако сообщение где-то теряется и до клиента доходит вот такой ответ:
[image: Response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была не в java. По сути handleException я вообще удалил. Response коректно отправлялся, моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я ожидал сообщение в заголовке, а оно передавалось в теле ответа, в формате json, помог мне в этом разобраться SoapUI